# How to send an embed on client ready

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a bot with discord.py.

I would like to send an embed to a specific discord channel when the bot is ready. To do that, here is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

logchannel = client.fetch_channel(692934456612487199)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Ticket Tool active as {client.user}')
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Jokz' Ticket Tool**", color=0xff0000, description="Started Successfully!")
    embed.set_footer(text="JokzTickets | @jokztools",icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1243255945913872384/jOxyDffX_400x400.jpg")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/check-mark-animated-gif-12.gif")
    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)

client.run(key)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\jokzc\Desktop\jokzticketspy> py index.py
Ticket Tool active as Jokz' Tools#5577
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jokzc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 15, in on_ready
    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
TypeError: send() takes no keyword arguments
```

What would the correct way to format this be?

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using? This looks like it might be caused because you are running a version before the rewrite, where sending an embed was a command by itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring out that it worked if I changed the function from client.fetch_channel to client.get_channel and I needed to put this in the actual on_ready function! The reason for this is because the client cannot get or fetch the channel until the client is actually ready.

The corrected code looks like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    logchannel = client.get_channel(692934456612487199)
    print(f'Ticket Tool active as {client.user}')
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Jokz' Ticket Tool**", color=0x00ff00, description="Started Successfully!")
    embed.set_footer(text="JokzTickets | @jokztools",icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1243255945913872384/jOxyDffX_400x400.jpg")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/check-mark-animated-gif-12.gif")
    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channelid = client.get_channel(id)
    botname = client.user.name
    print('message ' + botname)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Text", description="Text", color=discord.Color.red())
        
    embed.set_footer(text="Your text", icon_url="URL of icon")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="Url")
    await channelid.send(embed=embed)
```